# What is Apache Storm?

Tags: apache-storm

Hi I searched about this question but didnt find any answer which satisfies my mind. I am going to learn storm but before that I want to know that what is storm and why we use it? What's the objective of using storm in your project?

Any explanatory answer with example will be very appreciated instead of providing a link to some other site/question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too big to answer (with examples of course). Better to google. There are a lot of tutorials, examples, presentations and Storm books are already available.

Comment: Actually those links,book,presentations,examples are using very technical terms which I am unable to understand. Therefore asked here so I can get answer in simple words.

Comment: Storm is a really efficient system to manipulate data streams. It leverages to a distributed and fault-tolerant architecture to process a tons of messages in parralel. It can be used for instance to collect web clickstream, detect a network failures (sensors data analyses) or to distribute huge computations.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer this question but note that are many configuration to Strom, but it can help you understand if we need to use Storm, Oozie or some other technology.

Basically, Storm is used for stream - near real time processing,with linear scaling. 
If you need something that is more batch processing , you should use Oozie,schedule job & ect'

To understand Strom full option - you will need to read more and play around with it 
Hope this help you

Comment: `you should use Oozie,schedule job & ect`. That is a strong sentence. No, he shouldn't, there are other alternatives also.

Comment: @Chiron - this is indeed strong sentence - but I think it good for 2 sentence explanation if you need to use Strom or not. of course there are many ways to do things

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question asking for objectives on using Apache Storm in a project, a great place for answers is the Storm Powered By page which dicusses the use cases for companies like Alibaba, Baidu, Groupon, Loggly, Spotify, Twitter, WebMD, Yahoo!, Yelp and others.

Storm Use Cases: http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Powered-By.html